# How to make Bazel understand an #include relative to the WORKSPACE in combination with symlinks?

Tags: c++, bazel

By default, Bazel supports `#include`'ing files relative to the WORKSPACE directory. However, as soon as a relative `#include` path from the workspace root contains a symlink, this seems to no longer hold. For example, suppose we have some directory structure as follows:

```
WORKSPACE
libs/foo/src/foo.cpp
libs/foo/itf/foo.h
libs/foo/BUILD
foo -> libs/foo
```

Where `foo` in the root directory is a symlink to `libs/foo`. Suppose we have:

foo.h:

```
#pragma once 

void foo();
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo/itf/foo.h"

void foo() {}
```

BUILD:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["src/foo.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["itf/foo.h"],
)
```

In this case, `bazel build //...` gives the following error message:

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analyzed 2 targets (38 packages loaded, 166 targets configured).
INFO: Found 2 targets...
ERROR: [...]/foo/libs/foo/BUILD:3:11: Compiling libs/foo/src/foo.cpp failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF ... (remaining 16 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging

libs/foo/src/foo.cpp:1:10: fatal error: foo/itf/foo.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "foo/itf/foo.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is this a known issue or known behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Bazel is not aware of the symlink. Therefore this does not work - you have to change your include path to `libs/foo/itf/foo.h`. You can add `includes = ["libs"]` to the `cc_library` to get around this.

Comment: adding `includes = ["libs"]` does not work for some reason (I think since it is defined in `libs/foo/BUILD`, talking about some directory that is relative to the root of the workspace?). In any case, I will investigate how to make Bazel aware of the symlink.

Comment: Hmmm, even changing the `#include` directive does not work...Bazel is thoroughly confused here. I need to remove the `foo` symlink for the `#include` to 'libs/...' to work.